# retrieving database data - all at once or small amounts at a time - angular2

Tags: database, performance, sqlite, angular, filter

I'm very new to web dev so I'm not sure what the best way of doing this is. I'm making a web application to manage a item stock database. It is possible there could be upwards for 500,000 rows in the database. How should I manage this? I will be using angular2. There will be a search bar the users will use to search for items and also filters to filter the items by brand, item type, item weight, etc. I *must* use a sqlite database.

Methods I've thought of:

1. When the user navigates to the page that shows the items should I retrieve ALL (possibly 500,000 rows) of the data. Show maybe the first 50 items so there is something on the page, then as the user types into the search bar/uses the filters I assume I will be able to get the page to update the item list with 2 way data binding and use a very 'single page' feel that I think angular2 is used for and not have to query the database again since I already have all the items, etc. I'm not sure if retrieving that much data at once is a good thing or not?
2. When the user navigates to the page that shows the items just retrieve a small arbitrary amount so the page is populated with some items then as the user filters/searches I don't think I will be able to update the items list on the fly like in the first example? I think I will have to just query the database again when the user clicks the search button? Maybe add a event listener on the filters so that when one changes the database queries and gets the new items? Or?
3. Are neither of these the correct method and I should do it in some other way?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Hey..@user3238415 see [movies-finder](https://github.com/Lazhari/Movies-Finder). It helps you!!!

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look

Answer (score 0):

1. No, it is not a good thing to retrieve all the data at once, you should use paging and only show like 50 rows in a page (you decide the number)
2. Still paging seems a better idea, but yes, you will have to query the database again. For example at scroll down event (when you get to the last rows) query again the database with the following rows and add them to your page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Makes sense.

I'm going to do some googling, but do you know any good resources you can recommend me to do with paging techniques/tutorials.

Thanks again.

Comment: I don't really have any good doc for this, but I remember of reading about this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx